# Spring's JDBCTemplate IllegalArgumentException: datasource required

Tags: spring, derby, jdbctemplate, illegalargumentexception

Well, I am having a problem with configuring Spring's JDBCTemplate to work properly. I am trying to inject the datasource but it seems that it's always null. Here is a sample code:

1. applicationContext.xml:

   ```
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
   <property name="url"
       value="jdbc:derby:c:\\Derby\\MyDB\\jsfkickstart;create=true" />
   <property name="username" value="admin" />
   <property name="password" value="admin" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="employeeDoa" class="com.kickstart.employeeapp.doa.EmployeeDoa">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
   </bean>
   ```
2. web.xml

   ```
   <context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
   ```

   ```
   <listener>
           <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <listener>
           <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   ```
3. EmployeeDoa.java

   ```
   public class EmployeeDoa implements IEmployeeDoa, IDepartmentDoa {
   private DataSource dataSource;
           public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
           JdbcTemplate select = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
           return select.query(
                   "SELECT "+
                       "e.ID as empId, "+
                       "e.FIRSTNAME as empFirstName, "+ 
                       "e.LASTNAME as empLastName,  "+
                       "d.ID as depId,  "+
                       "d.NAME as depName, "+
                       "d.LOCATION as depLocation "+
                   "FROM jsfkickstart.Employee e, jsfkickstart.Department d",
                   new EmployeeMapper());
           }
   }

   class EmployeeMapper implements RowMapper {
       public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
           Employee emp = new Employee();
           emp.setId(rs.getInt("empId"));
           emp.setFirstName(rs.getString("empFirstName"));
           emp.setLastName(rs.getString("empLastName"));
           Department dep = new Department();
           dep.setId(rs.getShort("depId"));
           dep.setLocation(rs.getString("depLocation"));
           dep.setName(rs.getString("depName"));
           emp.setDepartment(dep);
           return emp;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Exception Thrown:

   ```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
   at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcAccessor.java:134)
   at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.<init>(JdbcTemplate.java:142)
   at com.kickstart.employeeapp.doa.EmployeeDoa.addEmployee(EmployeeDoa.java:29)
   ```

Does anybody know how can I resolve this problem? If I'm missing any important information in the question, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: give the code of com.kickstart.employeeapp.doa.EmployeeDoa (at least the class declaration)

Answer (score 2):

I was actually a very stupid exception. The body of the setDataSource() was empty, i.e. I didn't assigned dataSource to anything so it was always null.

Stupid me!!!

Comment: I was going to say I didn't see a setDataSource() method at all.